# Binary file into byte array from stdin - Java

Tags: java, io, binary, stdin

I had written a programm that loaded my binary file into a byte array, like this.

```
Path p = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("", "myFile");
byte [] fileData = Files.readAllBytes(p);
```

But the problem is that in my assignement the files are given from standard in, like this:

```
$ java -cp project.jar programm < file.sec
```

So I want to do the same like before but from stdin, is there an easy way to do this conversion?

Comment: It is not a good idea to read binary data from stdin...

Comment: I know but that is the assignment ;) they pass the files like that